# how to back 1 level of path directory in oracle XMLTYPE XMLTABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to back 1 level of a folder in the path but it is not working property.
I tried to use "../" and "./" but didn't work.
How can i Do this in Oracle?

```
WITH xmlPrePos as 
(
  select
    IDPraga,
    IDUsina,
    replace(valor, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>','') as XML    
  from dbo_Config
  where SiglaCategoria = 'ConfigFiltros' and Sigla='ConfigFiltros'
)
    SELECT 
        IDPraga,
        IDUsina,
        IDTpVinculo,
        Descricao,
        Reforma
    FROM xmlPrePos,
        xmltable('/ConfiguracaoFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros'
    passing XMLTYPE(xmlPrePos.XML)
    COLUMNS 
        IDTpVinculo INT path 'IDTpVinculo',
        Descricao VARCHAR(100) path 'Descricao',
        Reforma VARCHAR(100) path '../../SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros/Reforma');
```

the last line is the code i'm having the issue.
my return is null.

XML>

```
<ConfiguracaoFiltros xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
    <Reforma>VERDADEIRO</Reforma>
    <Bloqueio>NAO_IMPORTA</Bloqueio>
  </SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
  <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
      <IDTpVinculo>11</IDTpVinculo>
      <Descricao>ARRENDAMENTO / PARCERIA</Descricao>
    </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
      <IDTpVinculo>12</IDTpVinculo>
      <Descricao>PROPRIA</Descricao>
    </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
  </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
</ConfiguracaoFiltros>
```

Version>

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.6.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
"CORE   11.1.0.6.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.6.0 - Production

Waiting Result>

[image]

Comment: Please provide your oracle version and an example of your xml data

Comment: ... and your current and expected results. Why are you stripping out the `?xml` header?

Comment: added information in the question

Comment: 11.1 is an extremely old and buggy version...

Comment: I know that.. but unfortunately is the version the company is still using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As walking back up the tree doesn't seem to work in 11g, you can instead use two XMLTable calls:

```
WITH xmlPrePos as 
(
  select
    IDPraga,
    IDUsina,
    replace(valor, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>','') as XML    
  from dbo_Config
  where SiglaCategoria = 'ConfigFiltros' and Sigla='ConfigFiltros'
)
    SELECT 
        IDPraga,
        IDUsina,
        x2.IDTpVinculo,
        x2.Descricao,
        x1.Reforma
    FROM xmlPrePos
    CROSS JOIN xmltable(
        '/ConfiguracaoFiltros'
        passing XMLTYPE(xmlPrePos.XML)
        COLUMNS 
            Reforma VARCHAR(100) path 'SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros/Reforma',
            TpVinculoConfigFiltros xmltype path 'TpVinculoConfigFiltros'
    ) x1
    CROSS JOIN xmltable(
        '/TpVinculoConfigFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros'
        passing x1.TpVinculoConfigFiltros
        COLUMNS 
            IDTpVinculo INT path 'IDTpVinculo',
            Descricao VARCHAR(100) path 'Descricao'
    ) x2;
```

which with your example gets:

```
IDPRAGA IDUSINA IDTPVINCULO DESCRICAO               REFORMA   
------- ------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------
      3       1          11 ARRENDAMENTO / PARCERIA VERDADEIRO
      3       1          12 PROPRIA                 VERDADEIRO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=36bd2a9aff3a8e8431706af0f1a63e62)

As @Sayan said, and I sort of commented, you shouldn't need to remove the XML header; it works with it left in, and doesn't need the CTE:

```
    SELECT 
        dc.IDPraga,
        dc.IDUsina,
        x2.IDTpVinculo,
        x2.Descricao,
        x1.Reforma
    FROM dbo_Config dc
    CROSS JOIN xmltable(
        '/ConfiguracaoFiltros'
        passing XMLTYPE(dc.valor)
        COLUMNS 
            Reforma VARCHAR(100) path 'SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros/Reforma',
            TpVinculoConfigFiltros xmltype path 'TpVinculoConfigFiltros'
    ) x1
    CROSS JOIN xmltable(
        '/TpVinculoConfigFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros'
        passing x1.TpVinculoConfigFiltros
        COLUMNS 
            IDTpVinculo INT path 'IDTpVinculo',
            Descricao VARCHAR(100) path 'Descricao'
    ) x2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5b6dbd586d4fad6a3c503159e7a0a469)

Comment: it's working like a charm \o/.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you data looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <ConfiguracaoFiltros>
    <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
      <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
        <IDTpVinculo>1</IDTpVinculo>
        <Descricao>Test1</Descricao>
      </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    <SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
      <Reforma>Reforma Test1</Reforma>
    </SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
  </ConfiguracaoFiltros>
```

You can just simple add `./` before `../../`:
[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0879dda7156b5c0e484abf073e392c0)

```
WITH 
dbo_Config as (
select
  'ConfigFiltros' SiglaCategoria,
  'ConfigFiltros' Sigla,
  'IDPraga' IDPraga,
  'IDUsina' IDUsina,
  q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <ConfiguracaoFiltros>
    <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
      <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
        <IDTpVinculo>1</IDTpVinculo>
        <Descricao>Test1</Descricao>
      </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    <SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
      <Reforma>Reforma Test1</Reforma>
    </SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
  </ConfiguracaoFiltros>
  ]' as valor
from dual
)
,xmlPrePos as 
(
  select
    IDPraga,
    IDUsina,
    replace(valor, '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>','') as XML    
  from dbo_Config
  where SiglaCategoria = 'ConfigFiltros' and Sigla='ConfigFiltros'
)
    SELECT 
        IDPraga,
        IDUsina,
        IDTpVinculo,
        Descricao,
        Reforma
    FROM xmlPrePos,
        xmltable('/ConfiguracaoFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros'
    passing XMLTYPE(xmlPrePos.XML)
    COLUMNS 
        IDTpVinculo INT path 'IDTpVinculo',
        Descricao VARCHAR(100) path 'Descricao',
        Reforma VARCHAR(100) path './../../SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros/Reforma');
```

But I wouldn't remove `<?xml ...?>` header:
[DBFiddle2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c0df9ccc5265a35e16c250cae0d8034e)

```sql
WITH 
dbo_Config as (
select
  'ConfigFiltros' SiglaCategoria,
  'ConfigFiltros' Sigla,
  'IDPraga' IDPraga,
  'IDUsina' IDUsina,
  q'[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
  <ConfiguracaoFiltros>
    <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
      <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
        <IDTpVinculo>1</IDTpVinculo>
        <Descricao>Test1</Descricao>
      </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    <SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
      <Reforma>Reforma Test1</Reforma>
    </SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
  </ConfiguracaoFiltros>
  ]' as valor
from dual
)
,xmlPrePos as 
(
  select
    IDPraga,
    IDUsina,
    valor as XML    
  from dbo_Config
  where SiglaCategoria = 'ConfigFiltros' and Sigla='ConfigFiltros'
)
    SELECT 
        IDPraga,
        IDUsina,
        IDTpVinculo,
        Descricao,
        Reforma
    FROM xmlPrePos,
        xmltable('/ConfiguracaoFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros'
    passing XMLTYPE(xmlPrePos.XML)
    COLUMNS 
        IDTpVinculo INT path 'IDTpVinculo',
        Descricao VARCHAR(100) path 'Descricao',
        Reforma VARCHAR(100) path './../../SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros/Reforma');
```

The same example but with your updated data on DBFiffle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23c0d9d500d0b87f1bc3469efd4960b9

Comment: I tried this but the return is NULL where should bring "VERDADEIRO".. or "Reforma Test1" (in yout xml example)

Comment: the Columns "Reforma" keep returning NULL

Comment: @FernandoFefu yeah, I've just remembered that there was a bug in 11.1 with it. One sec, I'll add another answer with a workaround for that

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for Oracle <11.2:

```sql
WITH 
dbo_Config as (
select
  'ConfigFiltros' SiglaCategoria,
  'ConfigFiltros' Sigla,
  'IDPraga' IDPraga,
  'IDUsina' IDUsina,
  q'[<ConfiguracaoFiltros xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
    <Reforma>VERDADEIRO</Reforma>
    <Bloqueio>NAO_IMPORTA</Bloqueio>
  </SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros>
  <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
      <IDTpVinculo>11</IDTpVinculo>
      <Descricao>ARRENDAMENTO / PARCERIA</Descricao>
    </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
    <TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
      <IDTpVinculo>12</IDTpVinculo>
      <Descricao>PROPRIA</Descricao>
    </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
  </TpVinculoConfigFiltros>
</ConfiguracaoFiltros>
  ]' as valor
from dual
)
,xmlPrePos as 
(
  select
    IDPraga,
    IDUsina,
    valor as XML    
  from dbo_Config
  where SiglaCategoria = 'ConfigFiltros' and Sigla='ConfigFiltros'
)
    SELECT 
        IDPraga,
        IDUsina,
        xdata.*
    FROM xmlPrePos,
        xmltable(
          '
          for $x in ./ConfiguracaoFiltros
            for $y in $x/TpVinculoConfigFiltros/TpVinculoConfigFiltros
              return <row>
                       {$y}
                       {$x/SituacaoAreasConfigFiltros/Reforma}
                     </row>'
    passing XMLTYPE(xmlPrePos.XML)
    COLUMNS 
        xdata        xmltype      path '.',
        IDTpVinculo  INT          path './TpVinculoConfigFiltros/IDTpVinculo',
        Descricao    VARCHAR(100) path './TpVinculoConfigFiltros/Descricao',
        Reforma      VARCHAR(100) path 'Reforma'
        ) xdata;
```